# Words and their derivatives and their meanings

Tags: meaning

Whenever I find a new word I look it up in an English-to-English dictionary. Sometime it happens that the word I am looking for is not listed in the dictionary, but the other form of it is listed.

For example, I found the word **Hegemonic** from this sentence - **However, the country is not an all-powerful hegemonic state**. But in dictionary **Hegemony** is listed. **Hegemony** is noun, and **Hegemonic** is derived from it.

Now I have problem understanding the meaning of **Hegemonic state**, though I came to know the meaning of **Hegemony** perfectly.

It's not with a single word **Hegemony**, it happens with some other new words as well. So how to solve this problem? Can you please suggest me something to cope up with this problem?

Comment: I don't get this. If you understand *hegemony*, what's so difficult about understanding the derived adjective *hegemonic* applied to such an obviously suitable noun as *state?* Do you have the same problem with *democracy* and *a democratic state?*

Comment: I'm also not understanding why it's difficult - is the problem that you're having trouble finding the dictionary entry for the derived word? It seems simple (to me) to understand that the adjective version of Hegemony applied to the noun state would mean a state that is dominant over other states. I've found a [direct definition of hegemonic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hegemonic) so I'm confused. Would you explain a little more to help me understand?

Comment: I have a little trouble understanding it myself.  Hegemony is the strong influence an entity has upon others. The quality of that influence is that it is hegemonic. But is the state that exerts such influence itself hegemonic?

Comment: Just google for hegemonic and you'll find dictionaries that have that word, eg dictionary.com.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is used to described other objects that have qualities of the noun. *Hegemonic* describes objects that have qualities of *Hegemony*.

> However, the country is not an all-powerful hegemonic state.

The word state in this sentence means country or nation.

> However, the country is not an all-powerful hegemonic country.
>
> However, the country is not an all-powerful state that would exhibit hegemony.